# Illegal Argument Exception in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I'd like to perform a Hibernate query to get the number of "Coordinators" within a Group. A "Coordinator" has an admin-like role of a group.

At a higher level, I have two tables: domaingroup and group_coordinators. The latter table has 2 columns: coordinators_id and domaingroup_id. I'd like to check the # of rows for a particular user (shown in coordinators_id) and group (shown in domaingroup_id).

I get the error,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException:
>   DomainGroup.Group_Coordinators is not \ mapped

for the query,

```
SELECT Coordinators_Id=:followerId FROM DomainGroup.Group_Coordinators 
WHERE Coordinators_Id=:followerId and DomainGroup_id=:followingId
```

for the code,

```
 class DomainGroup ... {

                /**
                 * List of coordinators for this group.
                 */
                @Size(min = 1, message = MIN_COORDINATORS_MESSAGE)
                @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = 
        { CascadeType.PERSIST })
                @JoinTable(name = "Group_Coordinators")
                private Set<Person> coordinators;
```

Please advise me on how to properly execute this query.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two big mistakes: Forst you have to use Java class and member names in HQL queries, not the table names. And then you can't select from a java set; instead you have to specify the class.

In your example it will be sth. like

```
FROM Person WHERE Id=:followerId and DomainGroupId=:followingId
```

or

```
SELECT count(Id) FROM Person WHERE DomainGroupId=:followingId
```

(for the example I guess in the class Person, which you didn't provide, there are the mapped member variables Id and DomainGroupId)

Comment: Johanna - thanks. But in those 2 queries, there's no info about Group Coordinators...